# Auto-updating directory-listing?

Tags: command-line, bash

I would like to have a directory listing `ls .` that auto-updates its output when files are added and removed to the directory.

Is that possible or is there another commandline tool which can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

watch ls . is a command line tool you want to use. it will run it in a loop